# In SAS, When creating a ODS RTF File, the first page displays header part as PAGE 1 of 1 even though it has n number of pages

Tags: sas-ods

Using SAS,,, When creating a ODS RTF File, the first page displays PAGE 1 of 1 even though it has 20 pages for example. I used the following code:

```
'ods rtf file ="<path>\<filename.rtf";
ods escapechar='^';
title "Page ^{thispage} of ^{lastpage}";
/** <proc report satement>; **/
ods rtf close;'
```

All the other pages has the page numbers displayed correctly. e.g., "Page 2 of 20"
Also, when i double kick anywhere on the firstpage, the page number gets automatically corrected. from "Page 1 of 1" to "Page 1 of 20"

help me by providing a solution..